# Spring Kafka Consumer - Print Kafka Lag Info

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have created a spring kafka consumer that reads from a topic. Is there a way to print lag information similar to how we print partition info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a command line tool...

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group myGroup

TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
myTopic                        0          66              66              0          -
```

**EDIT**

You could run the command line tool and capture the output...

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
        .command("/usr/local/bin/kafka-consumer-groups", "--bootstrap-server", "localhost:9092",
                "--describe", "--group", "siTestGroup")
        .start();
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
process.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, baos);
System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. Is there a way to do it programatically using Spring Kafka. I wanted print the lag as part of my log messages.

Comment: Not currently; unlike the Scala version, the Java version of `AdminClient` doesn't have the `describeConsumerGroup()` method. You would have to add the scala jar to the classpath and write a Scala class to do much of what is currently in `ConsumerGroupCommand.KafkaConsumerGroupService`.

Comment: Thanks for your help , Gary. Is there a way for me to add this feature request?

Comment: You would have to open a [new feature request on the Kafka JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA) to ask them to implement the method on the java `AdminClient`. If you just want to log the info, I have added an edit to my question for one way to work around the limitation.

Answer (score 6):

Whereas no source code has been provided, I am under the assumption that you implemented your consumer through the **@KafkaListener** annotation. 
I have overcome the same problem you described making use of the **org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer** interface, as stated [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/807). It can be declared as a parameter in the consumer method under the **@KafkaListener** annotation.
This interface provides the **metrics()** method which contains the consumer lag information stored in the *records-max-lag* property.

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);

@KafkaListener(topics = "your-topic", groupId = "your-group-id", id = "your-client-id", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listenerExample(List<String> msgs, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets, Acknowledgment ack,
        Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {



    String lag = consumer.metrics().values().stream().filter(m -> "records-lag-max".equals(m.metricName().name()))
            .map(Metric::metricValue).map(Object::toString).distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.joining("", "[Kafka current consumer lag]", " records"));


    LOGGER.info(lag);


}
```

In this case, I explicitly chose the *records-lag-max* property. You could have chosen any other consumer metric, the list is at [Confluent Docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html#fetch-metrics).

The above code snippet will have the following output:
`[Kafka current consumer lag] X records`
Where X is the maximum lag in terms of number of records for any partition in this window.

### Important:

I am using version **2.3.3.RELEASE** of the **Spring Kafka** library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```